# Cannot install Cordova Fullscreen plugin, platform=Windows 10

Tags: windows, cordova, plugins, fullscreen

I'm using Cordova to create a Universal Windows 10 app for the desktop. I'm having problems installing the Fullscreen plugin at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fs-plugin-fullscreen . I use the CLI and cd to my project folder. When I use the CLI to install the plugin, I get the following error:

"Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/filfat-Studios-AB/cordova-plugin-fullscreen via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module"

It isn't a connection issue insofar as the internet connection is fine. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--nofetch` option.

```
cordova plugin add your_plugin_url --nofetch
```

In your case, it will be:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/filfat-Studios-AB/cordova-plugin-fullscreen --nofetch
```

But, make sure, you are using Cordova 7.x.x.

`--nofetch` option is removed in Cordova 8.0.0.